# C# - Loop only when a number changes

Tags: c#

Example of my code:

```
string value = client.DownloadString("http://www.site.com/value.html"); // There is a value of something like a1x6b2xs2 (just one line with random numbers that changes randomly).
Console.WriteLine(value);
Console.ReadKey();
```

That's all the code! I need to make the console write the number again only if the value in the site got changed! And make it a nonstop loop, just write the number again and again, but only if the old value is changed.

Comment: The question is not very clear to me. Did you mean something like : `int newValue = getValueFromHtml(); if (newValue != oldValue) display(); oldValue = newValue;` ? Or did you want to stop checking for differences regularly and be somehow informed that a change in the file occurred (which might or might not be feasible anyway) ?

Comment: I just edited the question so if someone can understand it now :P

Comment: Did you try any of the answers provided? I think most people understood what you were looking for, since everyone gave a similar answer.  Even Loomchild.

Answer (score 7):

Why don't you just keep the previous number in a variable and check that before printing?

```
int previousNumber = int.MinValue; // some invalid value 
while (isRunning) {
    // wait three minutes
    int currentNumber = GetNumberFromSite();
    if (currentNumber != previousNumber) {
        Console.WriteLine(currentNumber);
        previousNumber = currentNumber;
    }
}
```

Comment: Surely, it can't be that simple.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to store the old value, and check it before outputting the new one.

```
int oldVal = -1;

while (true)
{
  int newVal = GetNewValue();
  if (newVal != oldVal)
  {
     Console.WriteLine(newVal);
     oldVal = newVal ;
  }
  Thread.Sleep(1000 * 60 * 3)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
int current = ...;
int prev = current;
while(true)
{
    // get new number in current
    if(current != prev) 
        Console.WriteLine(current);
    prev = current;
    // wait 3 min
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int? oldNumber = null;


// in your loop reading from the website:
if (oldNumber != null && newNumber != oldNumber)
{
    oldNumber = newNumber;
    Console.WriteLine(newNumber);
}
```

Comment: Ooh, `int?`.  Didn't think of that one.  Good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx) that periodically checks whether or not that number has changed.

```
private System.Threading.Timer checkNumberTimer;
private int currentNumber;

private void InitTimer()
{
    //start immediately, interval is in TimeSpan
    checkNumberTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(
        timer_Elapsed,
        null,
        TimeSpan.Zero,
        Properties.Settings.Default.Interval
    );
}

private void timer_Elapsed(Object state)
{
    int oldNumber = currentNumber;
    currentNumber  =  CheckNumber();
    if( oldNumber != currentNumber  )
        ShowNewNumber( currentNumber );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write the value to a var, then check if it has changed?

```
int old, new
new = getValue(file.html)
if new != old then
  write(new) 
old = new
```

You can translate it to working code yourself.