# Checking the count in a while loop constantly throws messagebox when it shouldnt

Tags: c#

**Goal:**

I am aiming to notify the user then a new record is detected in MySQL table.

**What I am using:**

I am using `Windows form` and `MySQL`.

Also, within the code I am using `"SELECT COUNT(*)"` and store it into a variable to check the previous count and the new count.

**What I currently have coded:**

```
  public Dashboard()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //Timer to run function every 10 seconds
        System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        timer.Interval = 10000;
        timer.Elapsed += Notification;
        timer.Start();
    }

    //Track changes in MySQL table - and if new records appear then notify the user
    private void Notification(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        //MySQL connection
        using(var conn = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString.ConnString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            //Create command
            using(var cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) from tester", conn))
            {
                var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    //Current Number
                    int count = dr.GetInt32(0);

                    //Previous number
                    int prev_numb = int.MinValue;

                    while (true)
                    {
                        //If count is not same as previous number
                        if(count != prev_numb)
                        {
                            //Notify user
                            MessageBox.Show("New Record!");
                            //Set prev_numb to new numb
                            prev_numb = count;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Problem:**

The first part of the code works fine (Runs the function every 10 seconds).

But the messagbox keeps prompting every 10 seconds, even if the `count` has not changed... why is this happening? And what needs amending within the code to work as desired?

**Resources:**

Repeat function every n minutes
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34204679/12485722

Loop:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13051703/12485722

Comment: You might want to change the scope of ```prev_numb```. ```Count``` hasn't changed, but ```prev_numb``` has, is there any reason for setting it to ```int.MinValue```? Also, the ```while(true)``` loop seems to be unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is *you don't want a loop in the method at all*. The timer handles that for you. Additionally, the `count` needs to be a class member, rather than scoped to the method.

```
private int RecordCount = int.MinValue;

private void Notification(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    int newCount;
    using(var conn = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString.ConnString))
    using(var cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) from tester", conn))
    {
        conn.Open();
        newCount = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }

    if (RecordCount == int.MinValue) RecordCount = newCount;
    int diff = newCount - RecordCount;
    if (diff != 0)
    {
        RecordCount = newCount;
        MessageBox.Show($"{diff} new records!");
    }
}
```

I'm also a little nervous about putting a `MessageBox()`, which blocks for user input, inside a timer event. I might shift into a `Task()` (or similar, I'd have to think about it more) instead.

Comment: Hi - just got this error on cmd.executescalar()... `System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'` Regarding the messaegbox().. It's only for test purposes :)

Comment: the only way I can think to get that exception is if the table doesn't exist or you don't have permission to query it. Otherwise, you'll still get a `0`, even if there aren't rows.

Comment: It works! I used this `newCount = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());`

Comment: that sounds like somehow the MySql `count()` function is returning a string, which would be very strange, but it's MySql so I guess I shouldn't be too suprised.

Comment: But appreciate your answer! Really helped me out :D